# Trouble Connecting Android App to Raspberry Pi 3 over BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, android-ble

I am using the Raspberry Pi 3 model B as a bluetooth peripheral. 
The Pi is running a GATT server and advertising it as well.

I can connect to it from the LightBlue iOS app and can read and write values.

I am having trouble connecting to the Pi over BLE from an Android App.
I have tried using 2 apps from the play store - BLE Scanner and Bluetooth LE Scanner.
BluetoothLeGatt is another app I have tried using. It is available as an example BLE project on Android Studio. The pi appears in the scan results and once I press connect, the app tries to connect but is possibly refused connection by the pi. The program control goes to the GattCallback function with the state changed to 'disconnected' and the service discovery never happens.
The logs look like this:

```
D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: B8:27:EB:A4:E7:75, auto: false
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=0c46767a-1ddc-4d91-83fe-490f9d3a5ad7
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
D/BluetoothLeService: Trying to create a new connection.
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=6 device=B8:27:EB:A4:E7:75
I/BluetoothLeService: Disconnected from GATT server.
```

The same app is able to connect to a virtual peripheral simulated using the LightBlue iOS app or the DropBeacon iOS app.

This makes me think, some configuration on the pi is preventing it from accepting a connection from Android.

src code: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Any suggestion to make this work?
Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to advertise only for LE mode and not for Classic Mode from the Pi?

Answer (score 5):

Using

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback,TRANSPORT_LE);
```

instead of

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
```

did the trick for me. This function definition of connectGatt with 4 arguments is supported for API level 23

Comment: For those who need to call that method in lower versions of Android (where the method exists but it is private), take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27961521/1852787